# Assigning unique colors based on grouped variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataframe "data" and am trying to give each variable group their own unique color. The output should look like "data2". I was able to use base R using

```
  data$color <- c25[1:length(unique(data$variable))][match(data$variable, 
                                                           unique(data$variable))]
```

but, I am trying to be more comfortable using dplyr to perform the same task. How could I manipulate "data1" to generate "data2" using dplyr?

```
data <- structure(list(Sample.Number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Static", "D10 FB", "D12 FB", 
"D14 FB"), class = "factor"), value = c(9.61, 7, 6.59, 6.58, 
6, 5.93, 57.5, 45.5, 39.5, 39, 22.5, 21.5, 128.5, 78.5, 71.5, 
49, 40.5, 40, 36, 35, 390, 478, 298, 524, 474, 406, 478, 1043, 
448, 454, 519, 710, 838, 1481, 737, 305, 668, 1096, 340, 152, 
735, 760, 439, 882, 742, 730, 5923, 3697, 806, 927, 1726, 1436, 
593, 3545, 1669, 814, 1733, 2333, 819, 260, 586, 854, 506, 1067, 
747, 781, 1557, 3807, 1063, 1795, 1534, 2761, 666, 2887, 1737, 
1044, 2211, 2544, 1181, 322), color = c("black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black"
)), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = "data.frame")

c25 <- c("dodgerblue2", "#E31A1C", "green4", "#6A3D9A", "#FF7F00", "black", "gold1", 
         "skyblue2", "#FB9A99", "palegreen2", "#CAB2D6", "#FDBF6F", "gray70", 
         "khaki2", "maroon", "orchid1", "deeppink1", "blue1", "steelblue4", 
         "darkturquoise", "green1", "yellow4", "yellow3", "darkorange4", "brown")

data2 <- structure(list(Sample.Number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Static", "D10 FB", "D12 FB", 
"D14 FB"), class = "factor"), value = c(9.61, 7, 6.59, 6.58, 
6, 5.93, 57.5, 45.5, 39.5, 39, 22.5, 21.5, 128.5, 78.5, 71.5, 
49, 40.5, 40, 36, 35, 390, 478, 298, 524, 474, 406, 478, 1043, 
448, 454, 519, 710, 838, 1481, 737, 305, 668, 1096, 340, 152, 
735, 760, 439, 882, 742, 730, 5923, 3697, 806, 927, 1726, 1436, 
593, 3545, 1669, 814, 1733, 2333, 819, 260, 586, 854, 506, 1067, 
747, 781, 1557, 3807, 1063, 1795, 1534, 2761, 666, 2887, 1737, 
1044, 2211, 2544, 1181, 322), color = c("dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", 
"dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", 
"dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", 
"dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", 
"dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "dodgerblue2", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", 
"#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", 
"#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", 
"#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", "#E31A1C", 
"green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", 
"green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", 
"green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", "green4", "#6A3D9A", 
"#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", 
"#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", 
"#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", "#6A3D9A", 
"#6A3D9A")), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: your `data$variable` is a factor with 4 levels. Why do you need such a ling vector of colornames?

Comment: It's basically an example. I will have to routinely perform data manipulations like this, so I gave one from an old code before I learned how to use ggplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @MarBlo's idea of using the factors, I used mutate to do it

```
mutate(data, color = c25[as.numeric(factor(variable))])
```

Answer (score 0):

As `data$variable` is a factor with 4 levels you can use `mutate` in combination with `case_when`.

```r
levels(data$variable)
# [1] "Static" "D10 FB" "D12 FB" "D14 FB"

data %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(
    variable == 'Static' ~ 'dodgerblue2',
    variable == 'D10 FB' ~ '#E31A1C',
    variable == 'D12 FB' ~ 'green4',
    variable == 'D14 FB' ~ '6A3D9A',
    TRUE ~ 'black'
    ))
```

Comment: I was looking for a more automated method, but I used your idea of factors and used mutate().